# Convert image to base64 - Scriptcam

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using Scriptcam for taking photos of users when they register to my website.

The code that works to take the photos is:

```
function base64_tofield() {

    jQuery('#image').val(jQuery.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());

    jQuery('#preview').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + jQuery.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());

};
```

I would need to prefill the preview and the base64 field value, if they are already registered and they took their photo already. Can I pass the image URL to this function somehow?